# Internal exception thrown during REST serialisation causes HTTP 401?

Tags: asp.net, iis, rest

We have a REST service deployed in production, which returns an XML serialised representation of a simple object.

When calling the REST 'get' method, we see a very strange problem, whereby after all our user code is finished (according to our own logs), we get a 401 in the browser which is rendering the object XML. It's failing server-side during the execution of the 'return' statement in the REST method.

We think we understand this part of the problem... The object contains an enum, whose value is actually returned from a database. In this particular case we have managed to assign an integer value to the enum which isn't defined in the Enumeration itself (This behaviour is permitted, and is the reason for Enum.IsDefined method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined.aspx)

Our assumption is that when the REST framework code processes the 'return' statement, it then tries to serialise the Enum to a text value, and blows up because no name (string) exists for the specified value.

Strangely though, rather than getting a yellow screen of death or similar, we get a 401 (and a prompt for credentials in the browser).

We were wondering if ASP.NET / IIS does some sort of Server.Transfer in these cases, but perhaps it doesn't have filesystem permissions to the page it is transferring to - ? We're baffled as to what is going on under the bonnet! There is no client-side redirect.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP status code of 401 means Unauthorized. From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error):

> **401 Unauthorized**
>       Similar to 403 Forbidden, but specifically for use when authentication is possible but has failed or not yet been provided.[2] The response must include a WWW-Authenticate header field containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource. See Basic access authentication and Digest access authentication.

I would start looking at how your authentication is set up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm familiar with what 401 means, I'm just not sure why it's being returned because of a serialisation error which is occuring inside FCL code. We don't get this problem if the XML serialisation works (e.g. we parse a valid enum value).

Comment: Oh I see. That is a strange error. Are you using straight ASP.NET or MVC?

Comment: Indeed! ...we're using vanilla ASP.NET